# C++ passing mother class as an argument to the method of lower class

Tags: c++, class, oop, void

I'm working with connected class and I want to pass a whole "higher object" to the method of lower class. Is it possible?
The idea of what I want to do:

```
class Boy
{
    class Hello
    {
        void Sayhello(//I want to pass there a object Boy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a reference to `Boy` to the `sayHello`. A minimal example:

```
struct Boy
{
    void print() { std::cout << "Boy\r\n"; }
    struct Hello
    {
        void Sayhello(Boy& ref)
        {
            ref.print();
        }
    };
};


int main()
{

    Boy b;
    Boy::Hello hello;
    hello.Sayhello(b);
    return 0;
}
```